# firestore/permission-denied - The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.] in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, google-signin

I am using Google Login with Firebase.
Authentication is working fine.

when firestore rules are insecure, request.auth come up with data while running in local emulator.

but when i make rules like following it shows request.auth is null,

```
    function isLoggedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, create, update: if isLoggedIn();
      allow delete: if false;
    }
```

and throws permission denied error.

**how to fix this?**

Comment: Are you logged in while making the request ?

Comment: yes i am logged in.

Comment: when i use this-
     ``` return true``` 
    i can see user details in request.auth

Comment: Can you share the code that is making request? If you are logged in then it should allow operations. The warning is because you are allowing all logged in users to edit any document in the users collection

Comment: firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', email)
                .get();

Comment: Can you log logged in user's UID right before the query so we know you are logged in? Also to make sure, you are using both auth and Firestore either on hosted version or emulator right ?

Comment: ok let me try this specific user